# How to fetch updates for Firebase project using CLI tools?

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I've set up Firebase command line tools. I've uploaded my files to Firebase Hosting. All is okay.

After this I changed Database rules via console in browser.

The question is: how to fetch (download) Firebase's files from server to my local directory?

I can't find such command neither on [Github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) nor on [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/) nor on [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/deploying).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This currently isn't possible, though I'll make note of this as a feature request.

In general, if you're using the CLI to deploy database rules we encourage you to *always* use the CLI to update the rules (or immediately copy and paste the newly-updated rules to your local copy). Since rules deployed by the CLI are often stored in version control systems, this is often the best way to make sure that a project with multiple contributors doesn't accidentally trample each other's rules.

Comment: Could you post link to this feature request here once you'll create it?

Comment: This should be updated to add @Duppy's answer information

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which version this became available.  But you can now manage rules via REST and the firebase cli

See these docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/app-management

From REST

- `curl 'https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/.settings/rules.json?auth=FIREBASE_SECRET'`

From [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/)

- `firebase database:get /.settings/rules`

Comment: Probably this is what I was needed. I will try this approach later.